# Best way / how to "touch" a lazy var?

Tags: ios, swift5

In custom views,

```
class Blah: UIView {
```

you use simple lazy vars for new layers

```
private lazy var bell: CALayer = { ...
}()
```

and then usually in say

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    .. whatever
    bell.frame = whatever
    donger.frame = whatever
    border.frame = whatever
}
```

All SOP.

However I was just working on a class where

```
private lazy var dot: CALayer = { ...
   as it happens, the frame is fixed
   nothing else is ever changed
}()
```

I suddenly realized, the lazy var "dot" is never "touched"!

So it never appears!

You can do this,

```
let _ = dot
```

no worries, but, what is the best syntax, the best way to "touch" a lazy var in Swift?

I never thought about this before!

Comment: Why touch it if it isn't used?

Comment: sigh, it appears (it should appear in the built view), but simply it never has to be modified!  so the lazy var never instantiates!   - = works fine, but there must be a better way

Comment: Why make it a `lazy` var?

Comment: @DonMag - that's a good question (how else would you do it then?) but, it's good engineering to make it a lazy var since (1) such things are always lazy vars. (2) in the example, as it happens you never need to do something to "dot" , during this cycle of development, but, it would be perfectly natural that next week, for some reason we need to go dot.something = something, animate the position or what have you; so then you'd want it as a lazy var in the usual pattern.  In short, the answer to your Q is "it's good to stick to patterns".

Comment: But anyway, again, as such it's just an interesting question; what's the best Swift idiom to "touch" a lazy var !

Comment: What do you mean by the "best way"? That could be opinion-based if you don't define what is "best". The "Swifty" way is of course to not do this at all.

Comment: @Fattie - I'm not 100% sure I agree with "it should always be lazy". The benefit of lazy is that it is not initialized until it is referenced -- and if you have, for example, a dozen objects of which only 3 will be used at any instance of the parent class, it makes sense in terms of memory / performance considerations. However, if you have a property / object that will always be used, there doesn't appear to be any benefit.

Comment: @Fattie - Plus, in your specific case... I'm not sure how `dot` could *appear in the built view* if it is never accessed? Doesn't something like: `layer.addSublayer(dot)` reference the object? And if you're not actually referencing it anywhere, why instantiate it (which would, in fact, totally negate any benefit of it being lazy)?

Comment: Hi Don, all true but.    In the context of making custom views, you always have lots and lots of lazy var (for each layer).  So say the project has 50 custom view .swift files and in each of them 1, 2, 15 custom layers.  the pattern for the whole project is that every single one of those is a lazy var.  So if ONE of them is like in my example - surprisingly it's never actually "touched" - you can see there's a lot to be said for keeping the pattern

Comment: hi Don, we typed over each other - just to repeat the best, normal, and usual pattern for custom layers in custom views is a lazy var.   (I just counted something like 200 in the project open in front...)  You can see what I'm saying, if one is "oddball" like this it's a shame to change the pattern.

Comment: "I'm not sure how dot could appear in the built view if it is never accessed.."  Well as I said, I touch it using "let _ = ..." which is a way to "touch" an object in Swift.  But it seems clunky, maybe there's a better idiom to "touch" in Swift.

Comment: @Fattie - I'm wondering if there is some fundamental misunderstanding here... Why do you want to "touch" the object? If it is not going to be used (referenced), there's no need to touch it. If it *is* going to be used, then it will be instantiated when it is used.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter (if that’s what you mean by “better”) way to do this is

```
_ = dot
```

This is the syntax you use to discard a value you don’t want. You’ve probably seen this used to discard the return value of a function call:

```
_ = functionWithSideEffects()
```